# ipad music player crash

Tags: ipad, music, crash

The music player on my iPad iOS 8.1.2 has started crashing. After playing half a dozen songs or so the music player stops completely. This is very recent behaviour. Whether the music is downloaded or cloud does not make a difference. All music is in my iTunes account.

I have rebooted the machine (let the battery run down to force a restart) but that has not fixed the music player. How can I restore normal music player function?

Comment: Does it just stop playing or actually crashes the app?

Comment: Crashes back to the home screen and loses its place in the playlist.

Comment: Does it has anything to do with play mode (random, continuous ect)

Comment: I only play playlists in order, don't do random or continuous, so no.

Comment: Thank you, I am just trying to work with you on this, and not taking the iOS out of equation, but it might be something else. If it was the iOS update the problem should occurred immediately. When playing single song it works, but playing multiple does not? Is it a album or your play list? Did you try making new play list?

Comment: I didn't use the music player immediately after the iOS update, so I cant speak to how fast the problem developed. I only know it appeared recently. The crash always has happened while playing a playlist, which I create from albums, basically. I have not made a new playlist recently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And you did check if it is a problem with that list, by using a new one?

Comment: Hi, I did make a new Genius playlist. The player made it through one song and then crashed back to the home screen.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to isolate the problem further.

- Syncing with iTunes will rebuild the iTunes database files and potentially correct artwork problems.
- playing new content might show that the existing content is in some way corrupt.
- backing up the device and erasing all content and settings might be a more drastic step to get a clean song or two.

If that crashes, restore your device. If not, you can restore the backup and continue isolating things that will cause the crash. There's no update for iTunes, but perhaps you just need to wait for iOS 8.2 to arrive if it's not anything you are causing. The fact that multiple songs cause a crash means it's more likely about the database file storing the playlists and not just a bad song or two. Your comment about it happening with music that once played fine also points to settings and metadata and not the songs themselves.

Comment: I have not added any music since before this started happening. I suspect the last iOS update a couple of weeks ago. Don't want to go through a backup and restore, I can play music on other devices until a new iOS update fixes things.

Comment: I don't know if an update will fix it. It's hard to know until you go through some troubleshooting steps to isolate what is causing the crash. You could also try resetting all settings from general in the settings app.

Comment: Thanks for the reset suggestion. I did that and logged in to iTunes Match again, got all my playlists and iCloud songs showing up, so all that should have been refreshed. The player still crashed out about halfway through the second playlist today, a playlist that I have listened to before. It feels like some buffer or memory storage function is overloading, and once it goes the player can only go so far into a song list then fails completely.